# How to get a bot to reply to a message on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a discord bot in python using discord.py to create a speech channel with a custom name when a command is executed. The channel is created but does not reply to the message. It tell `The application did not respond`.

This is the code of the bot

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Up and Ready!")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@bot.tree.command(name="hello")
async def create_channel(ctx, channel_name: str):
    guild = ctx.guild
    existing_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=f" | {channel_name}")

    if existing_channel:
        await ctx.send(f"Il canale '{channel_name}' esiste già.")
    else:
        category_name = "Live"  # Sostituisci con il nome della categoria desiderata

        # Trova la categoria per nome
        category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name=category_name)

        if category:
            member_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="︱Member")  # Sostituisci con il nome del ruolo "︱Member" personalizzato

            if member_role:
                overwrites = {
                    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False),  # Impedisce ai membri di connettersi
                    member_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=False),  # Impedisce ai membri di connettersi
                    guild.get_role(id_1): discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=True),  # Ruolo 1: ️︱Moderator
                    guild.get_role(id_2): discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=True),  # Ruolo 2: ️︱Trial Moderator
                    guild.get_role(id_3): discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=True),  # Ruolo 3: ️︱Helper
                    guild.get_role(id_4): discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect=True),  # Ruolo 4: ︱Content Creator
                }

                channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f" | {channel_name}", category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
                await ctx.send(f"Il canale vocale '{channel.mention}' è stato creato nella categoria '{category_name}'.")
            else:
                await ctx.send(f"Il ruolo '︱Member' non esiste.")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"La categoria '{category_name}' non esiste.")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

This is the error code in the terminal:

```
2023-06-10 21:56:03 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'hello'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\bot ds\main.py", line 42, in create_channel
    await ctx.send(f"Il canale vocale '{channel.mention}' è stato creato nella categoria '{category_name}'.")
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 860, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'hello' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I tried using different methods like replace `interaction.response.send_message` with `ctx.send`